# Google Cloud Platform - How to filter instances.list by tag?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to filter list of instances by tag name

What works perfectly with gcloud, e.g.

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter 'tags.items=firewall-client-mongodb'
```

Does not work with API, which always returns 400:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid value for field 'filter': 'tags.items = test'. Invalid list filter expression."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value for field 'filter': 'tags.items = test'. Invalid list filter expression."
 }
}
```

Is there any way to filter instances by tag, or any user defined variable? I'm testing with
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list

Comment: I found out, that wildcard works in API, e.g. name=web*. Better than nothing :-)

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider using labels. You can filter by labels using the API - ex: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#filter

Answer (score 3):

As of today, the following commands *should* now work:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--filter="tags.items=${TAG}" \
--project=${PROJECT}

#=>

NAME           ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE
my-machine     us-west1-c  f1-micro
```

and:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=us-west1-c

#=>

NAME           ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE
my-machine     us-west1-c  f1-micro
```

Curiously, it does **not** appear to work correctly with **both** `--filter` and `--zones` flags:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--filter="tags.items=${TAG}" \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zones=us-west1-c

#=>

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Invalid value for field 'filter': 'tags.items eq ".*\b${TAG}\b.*"'. Invalid list filter expression.
```

The underlying API call requires the `zone` to be provided; this command will **always** fail if a `--filter` flag is used.

This issue was filed [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143463446) if you wish to check on its status.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue and got the same error you got. This seems to be an issue with the API.
I would recommend you to Create new Compute Engine issue using this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=0) for issue trackers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `gcloud` `--filter` implementation is broken. Try quote your search pattern in parentheses:

```
gcloud ... --filter='term=(item-1 item-2)'
```

Dashes (`-`) might break DSL of `--format` ((

Official docs extensively encloses values in paretheses:

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/tips
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters

like:

> List Compute Engine instance resources with tag my-tag or my-other-tag:
>
> ```
> gcloud compute instances list  --filter="tags.items=(my-tag,my-other-tag)"
> ```

Comment: Thank you for this - I can confirm that this also works with container images that have multiple tags: `gcloud container images list-tags us.gcr.io/my-registry/my-image --filter='tags=(671)' --format=json` works while `filter='tags.items=671'` does not.